# MongoDB: Determining which Secondary is being read from

Tags: java, mongodb, database

Hey first time using mongo replica sets, and I've configured a set of 3 servers in Java. I'm trying to determine which secondary is being read from by my service (using secondary preferred). Does the mongo driver expose access to this info within Java? 
As I'm struggling to find a reliable way to track it. I'm also aware once a connection is made to a secondary it is unlikely to switch to read from the other secondary unless there is failure.

Comment: Let's take a step back. Why do you want to identify the secondary the reads come from? I can not think of a use case in which this would make any sense. Please explain the reason, maybe we can find a different and more elegant solution.

Comment: Recently one of our services that performs reads from our DB had a disk failure that caused it to run slow and thus the secondary began to lag behind the primary. As far as I can tell, the primary was suggesting it was dead however it threw no exceptions and the service persisted the connection to the slow server. I was planning on setting up the service to check the optime delay at set intervals and should a server fall behind, force it to refresh a connection and hopefully the driver would remove the slow server from the connection pool

Comment: How i'm going to replicate the issue in test i'm not sure and that's a whole different story. Knowing what server I was reading from was mostly so when I came to test I could see if the switch was occurring is some other way than checking the rs.status() against the primary

Comment: I fail to see how those reads of your application server caused the MongoDB secondary to lag. If the replica set decides a secondary is dead, you'll simply be answered from the other secondary, if available. To monitor the delay, simply connect to the instance directly and get your info from there.

Comment: From what I've read about request association in mongo, once a connection is established it will not change the connection until the thread ends, read preference is changed or a socket error is thrown? From what I can tell the slow speeds on the secondary server's hardware breaking did not trigger any of these cases and therefore the connection pool was not refreshed, this is the only reason I have found that would suggest why it simply didn't read from the other secondary as you have outlined.

Comment: The drivers are replica set aware. If a server becomes unavailable, the driver should notice. A read or write of course could fail and should be handled accordingly. I usually give a grace period of some 5 seconds in a catch block and retry the operation. Not beautiful, not overly efficient, but works. Still, I can not see in which way a disk failure of the app server should stall the secondary – unless they are both on the same machine, of course (which is a horrible idea).

Comment: I guess i'll have to investigate more into why the other secondary wasn't allocated the work, as they aren't located on the same machine and If the service isn't doing anything weird. I appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getAdress` method like below, see the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.10.0/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html) for more details.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
ServerAddress serverAdress = mongoClient.getAddress()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this returns the server address of the primary when I know i'm definitely connected to a secondary by the time I do a read, do you know of any ways to determine specifically which connection the read originated from?